# Meaning of だろうと

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the meaning of 「だろうと」 in the following sentence, and how can we translate last part of sentence (bold one)?

> 今や人型の死とした存在は、無感動な声で終わりの拳を握り締めた。彼の攻撃を防げる者など存在せず、**しかも何発だろうと発射可能。**

Comment: How is your translation looking so far? ^^;

Comment: その「(何~~)だろうと」は、「(何~~)でも」「(何~~)であろうと(も)」と同じで、この辞書だと http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/je2/51854/m0u/%E3%81%A7%E3%82%82/　5番のところの「何発でも」と同じ用法です。

Comment: you have a nice saying using it, 雨が降ろうが槍が降ろうが

Comment: (むしろ１文目が全く分からないです。「人型の死とした存在・・・」？？？)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Making an answer out of Chocolate's comment)

(何~~)だろうと means the same as (何~~)でも.

I don't know the context, but the last bit of the sentence means something like:

> [...] it is possible to fire as many shots as wished