# Meaning of なろうとなんだろうと

Tags: grammar

In a manga I found the following sentence:

> ボロボロに**なろうとなんだろうと**自分で気づくしかない

What does the `なろうとなんだろうと` means? The remaing part should mean something on the lines of "She must notice by himself [...] if she hurt herself", and the given translation is something like (I'm translating a translation, sorry for any inaccuracy) "Even if she will hurt himself, he must notice it by himself".

I found a couple of questions ([here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/11943/meaning-of-%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%A8) and [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/37079/what-does-%E3%81%AA%E3%82%93%E3%81%A0%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%91%E3%81%A9%E3%81%AA-mean-here)) in which part of that expressione appears, but they doesn't really seem to apply; a Google search wasn't helpful, either, and my grammars doesn't have that form, which maybe is a mix of multiple forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「ボロボロになろうとなんだろうと自分{じぶん}で気{き}づくしかない。」

First, allow me to start from the basic.

> 「Verb in Volitional Form + と or が + Phrase」

is a very common expression meaning:

> "Verb + ても関係{かんけい}なく + Phrase" =
>
> "Even if [verb], [Phrase]."

Thus, 「ボロボロになろう**と**」 means "**Even if one/you/I were torn to shreds**".

Moving on to 「ボロボロになろうと**なんだろうと**」...

The 「なんだろうと」 part does not really hold an independent meaning of its own.  The sentence in question would mean practically the same without 「なんだろうと」.  So, why is it there?

「なんだろうと」, in this context, simply emphasizes the sub-clause 「ボロボロになろうと」.  As one can see, 「だろうと」 and 「なろうと」  rhyme perfectly; therefore, it creates a good rhythm that is lively and emphatic.

You will often hear phrases in the same construct such as:

・「かわいいネコちゃん**だろうがなんだろうが**、オレは動物が苦手なんだって！」

・「東京**だろうがどこだろうが**行っちゃえよ。もうお前の顔は見たくねえ！」

・「森田**だろうがだれだろうが**いらないって。オレは一人でこの仕事をしたいんだって。」

Notice that the question word changes according to what you are emphasizing -- なん、どこ、だれ、どう, etc.

Comment: That's very helpful, thanks. Could I also ask what `・「東京だろうがどこだろうが行っちゃえよ。もうお前の顔は見たくねえ！」` means? I'm studying your examples to better understand this construct, and I'm not sure about the `東京だろうがどこだろうが行っちゃえよ` part: it sounds like "Even if it's Tokyo, go [there], I don't want to see your face again", but I'm not sure. I'm guessing `っちゃえ` is `ちゃう < しまう` with imperative `-え`. Also, does `"Verb + ても関係なく + Phrase"` literally means "Even if [verb] has no relation, [phrase]?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are translation of **ボロボロになろうと** → "Even if they will hurt themselves a lot" is correct.

Though I can't find any reference, I think this **なんだろうと** means "or anything", "or whatever". However, you might not need to explicitly use "or anything", or "or whatever" since it's redundant and "even if" means なろうとなんだろうと.

> *Even if it rains a lot, I will go to work.*

"Even if" says any antecedents will not change the conclusion :
"I will go to work". (Train might prevent you from doing so though, you want go to work in any situations)

There is an idiomatic expression using a similar structure: [雨が降ろうと、槍が降ろうと](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E9%9B%A8%E3%81%8C%E9%99%8D%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C%E6%A7%8D%E3%81%8C%E9%99%8D%E3%82%8D%E3%81%86%E3%81%8C/) .
「どんな困難があってもやりとげるという強い決意のたとえ。石にかじりついても。」

> ボロボロに**なろうとなんだろうと**自分で気づくしかない

So, add them together,  "*Even if they will hurt themselves a lot (or whatever), they need to realize on their own*"

Comment: With «Probably you actually do not need to translate なろうとなんだろうと with this conditional "Even if"» do you mean I can just translate the conditional meaning with "Even if" and ignore the nuances like "or whatever"?

Comment: @Mauro It seems to me l'électeur nailed down your answer clearly.

Comment: Yes, thanks; I'm just waiting a bit before accepting their answer since it happened to me in the past to accept an answer only to get a better one after; since then I tend to wait a bit before accepting, I'll accept it in a bit.